# Error message when putting model predictions in raster format

Tags: raster, r-raster

I am trying R and the raster package to put model predictions back into a raster format but I get an error message. My code:

```
# get any raster from the dataset to use as a template for the predictions 
r2 <- Ras1[[2]] 

# assign the predicted values (map_real2) to it
values(r2) <- map_real2
```

The error message:

```
Error in setValues(x, value) : 
length(values) is not equal to ncell(x), or to 1
```

I have a feeling this error is about names and name order but, if so, I dont know how to fix it.

I tried to make the names in the raster stack the same order as the model:

```
m <- xgb_train_1$finalModel
name <- m$feature_names
Ras1 <- Ras[[name]]
Ras1[names]
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a complete, self-contained, reproducible example. For inspiration see the examples in `?raster::predict` or `terra::predict`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a whole bunch but honestly here https://www.neonscience.org/resources/learning-hub/tutorials/raster-data-r
and
https://rspatial.org/spatial/8-rastermanip.html#
is where you will learn everything you need to accomplish what you need. They are clear and not just a wall of text to wade through.

If you want to see my thoughts then wade through them, but I learned it all starting with these and years of working in ArcGIS before R.

I suspect your struggles are due to working with lists of lists of rasters which is challenging to wrap your head around.

If you add details of how your rasters and predictive data are stored and the format of the predictive data I can definitely help you.

Your question really doesn't give the information needed to answer your specific question. However I suggest you edit your question to include the output format of your prediction data. Is it already spatial data with CRS, origin, extent, ymin, ymax, etc? Is it in Geotiff or similar format? Is it an array or matrix? ASCII?

What packages are you using? Raster? GDAL? SP? Stars

```
    m <- xgb_train_1$finalModel # What is xgb_train_1? What is final model?  
                              Are these raster objects already? 
name <- m$feature_names # are you just pulling the list of names from the 
                           model results and this is a list of names for 
                           the rasters?
Ras1 <- Ras[[name]] # what is Ras? This is how I would create a raster out 
                       of a list of rasters called Ras and name was one of 
                       the rasters in the list
Ras1[names] #what is names?
```

I will tell you how I do it and maybe it will help but maybe our data is nothing alike so it won't be helpful for you.

Keep in mind that I work with very large rasters, like 9g each, so I cannot work with things stored within Rs working memory. That probably makes this much more complicated than your process.

I would not create a template and then assign new values to that template. I would simply assign the results of the model to a new raster object. I work extensively with building new rasters and predictions based on models with rasters as the covariates. There are many ways to do this depending on modeling program and methods so there is no one way. Actually, creating new raster objects with the same info as existing rasters isn't specific to predictive data so it really doesn't matter.

I start with rasters and spatial data that already have matching spatial parameters. Within a project all of my rasters and shapefiles etc are derived from the same geographic area and I start each project by ensuring that all of my input rasters and spatial data files have the same CRS, pixel sizes, extent, origin, etc and doing what is needed to make them all the same if necessary.

If you have one raster that has all of these things that you want all other rasters to match you can use it to set all the rest so they are the same.

Here is some code for the crs for my spatial data

```
crs = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +nodefs"), remove = F)
```

If you have a raster that you want everything to match then you can find that with

```
template_crs <-  CRS(Ras2[[2]]
crs
```

This will print out something similar to my crs above

You can also install GDAL - this will be necessary no matter what - and run and it will give you most of what you need to know about your template to make sure your prediction maps match.

```
GDALinfo("raster or path to raster")
```

For what it's worth here is some of my code for starting off programs to make sure rasters matched spatially

```
 setwd("F:/GRASS/Cara") 
# setting where all file paths start or go
    GDALinfo("PTCT/chjv_01071.tif")
#check raster info - this was in "PTCT" folder in "F:/GRASS/Cara/
    test_tif <- raster("PTCT/chjv_01071.tif")
# first I tested the GDAL info to make sure it matched everything else and then I create raster object by reading in an existing raster that was in the GeoTiff format
```

I was running functions that you had to specify a raster to make sure the output would match the spatial needs. I named it test_tiff

As I ensure everything I do it ALWAYS in this same CRS I don't have to spend time with templates. I put the work up front and it works with what I do.

To create a raster from your output I would simply write this

```
r <- raster (map_real2) #creates raster from data appropriate for rasterization
writeRaster (r, file.path("folder/raster_name,.), format = "GTiff, overwrite = True or False depending on what you want) #Writes the raster into a location outside of the R environment, to the file path you specify, the last thing is the name and the format determines the file extension.
```

This would create a raster called raster_name.tiff in F:/GRASS/Cara/folder/ because I set my working directory at the beginning and added "folder/ before the raster name.